# Closure compiler onerror signature compilation

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have an error logging function that looks like this:

```
window.onerror = function (ErrorMsg, Url, LineNumber, Col, Error) { .... }
```

When I put my code through Closure Compiler, I get a warning:

```
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: assignment to property onerror of Window
found   : function (?, ?, ?, ?, ?): undefined
required: (function (string, string, number): ?|null) at line 197 character 1
    window.onerror = function (ErrorMsg, Url, LineNumber, Col, Error) {
```

What should I change in my function definition to clear the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Closure Compiler only accepts 3 arguments for `window.onerror`.  Here is the definition from the extern [w3c_dom1.js](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/externs/browser/w3c_dom1.js):

```
// onerror has a special signature.
// See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror
// and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197053(VS.85).aspx
/** @type {?function (string, string, number)} */
Window.prototype.onerror;
```

The type information isn't needed.  Here is an example that is working in some of my code:

```
/** Sets a global error handler function in `window.onerror` to alert user.
* @return {undefined}
* @static
*/
UtilityCore.setErrorHandler = function() {
  window.onerror = function(msg, url, line) {
    var s = msg + "\n" + url + ":" + line;
    if (goog.DEBUG) {
      console.log(s);
    }
    if (UtilityCore.numErrors++ < UtilityCore.maxErrors) {
      alert(s);
      return true;
    }
  }
};
```

If you need all 5 arguments:

1. you could try casting the type to the 3 argument version
2. you can file an issue about it with the Closure Compiler project, or ask on their email list.

---

*previous answer:*

<strike>Here is something to try:</strike>

```
/**
* @param {string} ErrorMsg
* @param {string} Url
* @param {number} LineNumber
* @param {number} Col
* @param {Object} Error
*/
var errorFn = function (ErrorMsg, Url, LineNumber, Col, Error) { ... }
window.onerror = errorFn;
```

It seems that Closure Compiler only expects there to be 3 arguments, so that might still be a problem.

Comment: Tried it, it adds the same warning.

Comment: That makes sense in light of what I found out, see updated answer.

Comment: The `onerror` signature hasn't been updated with the latest signatures. You can send a Pull Request to get this changed. Most usage has switched to using `window.addEventListener('error', function(evt) {}, false)` instead. Modern browsers give the same information on the ErrorEvent object passed.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth: could you put your answer in code?

Comment: @frechie answer added.

Answer (score 0):

The `onerror` signature for the compiler hasn't been updated to match the latest browser specifications. You can send a Pull Request to get this changed.

Most usage has switched to using:

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(evt) {}, false)
```

Modern browsers give the same information on the [ErrorEvent object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent) passed to the event listener.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks. For the full copy-paste version of code, I added this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yr0aoubf/